# Break points are not hitting in the visual studio 2012 asp.net 4.0

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.0, visual-studio-debugging, windows-server-2012

I have upgraded my application from ASP.NET 2.0 to ASP.NET 4.0 ( also from VS 2005 to VS 2012). There is a strange problem I am facing during debugging my application. None of the breakpoints in my web application's codebehind file hits. It says: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Project configurations are below:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

- Platform target: Any CPU
- Configuration: Debug
- Environment: Windows Sever 2012, IIS 8.0, VS 2012

I have tried:

- Deleting .pdb file / bin folder
- Cleaning, rebuilding whole project
- resetting IIS (8.0)
- Breakpoints are in the code execution path
- Attaching w3wp.exe process

but it didn't do any good.

**I have installed Visual Studio 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and "It worked absolutely fine" :o**

**BUT**

When I prepared a fresh machine (physical) having Windows Server 2012 and VS 2012, the break points are not being hit once agian. So I think there is some compatibality issue ( or any other issue or a bug) b/w Windows 2012 and VS 2012.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in VS2012. I was able to resolve by going to Project Properties | Build | Adavnced.  Then on the Advanced Build Setting dialog box I set the Output 'Debug Info' to full.